# Fetching first name and last name

Tags: ms-access

I have a data in tables as full name. These name contains "Last_Name, First Name Middle Name" I need to fetch first name, last name and middle name from full name and store them in different fields.

For example, I have full names in table as -

- Williams, Robert K
- Winchester, Sam T

I need to store them as

```
FirstName        Last_Name       MName
Robert            Williams         K
Sam               Winchester       T
```

I am doing it on some tables in Ms access. Can anybody please help me how I can achieve this.

Comment: I need clarity with what you are asking. You say "...and store them in different rows", yet later, you say to store them as columns. Please clarify what you are asking for, and please post any attempts you have made as well as the results

Comment: I want to save them as - first name - Robert, last name - Williams, middle name - K. I am storing them as columns only. I have tried one query - - - - - - - - - Expr: Right(Trim([Names]),Len(Trim([Names]))-InStr _
(InStr(1, [Names]," ")+1,[Names]," "))----------- this query give me middle name only to for those names who have middle name, otherwise full name. I'm stuck here for past few hours.

Comment: You want to parse name parts to separate columns (not rows). Manipulating strings requires consistency in structure. This will not be simple. Will the middle name always be an initial or nothing? This will quite likely require VBA.

Comment: Just a note on `FirstName, Last_Name, MName`: You are not really using 3 different naming conventions on 3 columns in one table, are you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a full name string into First, Last and Middle Initial in VBA Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452723/splitting-a-full-name-string-into-first-last-and-middle-initial-in-vba-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt at a non-VBA solution:

```sql
select
    iif(t.name like "*,*", trim(mid(t.name, instr(t.name, ",")+1, len(t.name) - instr(t.name, ",") - iif(t.name like "* ?", 2, 0))), iif(t.name like "* ?", left(t.name, len(t.name)-2), t.name)) as FName, 
    iif(t.name like "*,*", left(t.name, instr(t.name, ",")-1), Null) as LName,
    iif(trim(t.name) like "* ?", right(trim(t.name), 1), Null) as MName
from
    YourTable t
```

Change `YourTable` to suit your table name.

#### Assumptions

- The absence of a comma implies that the name is a first name (and possible middle-initial).
- Middle initials are assumed to always be 1 character

#### Examples

Given the sample data:

```
+--------------------+
|        Name        |
+--------------------+
| Williams, Robert K |
| Winchester, Sam T  |
| Smith, John        |
| Jack A             |
| Harry              |
| ,Thomas T          |
+--------------------+
```

The above query will yield:

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| FName  |   LName    | MName |
+--------+------------+-------+
| Robert | Williams   | K     |
| Sam    | Winchester | T     |
| John   | Smith      |       |
| Jack   |            | A     |
| Harry  |            |       |
| Thomas |            | T     |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but ONLY if your data is consistant.

What about

Williams, Robert

Or

,Robert

So, was every full name perfectly entered? In my experience this is VERY RARE.

So, the challenge here is not code or a update that splits out all 3 but dealing with data that does NOT have all 3 settings.

The following code should work, and it attempts to deal with missing parts, but how well this code works will much depend on how well and how consistant the full name data is.

So, this code can be placed in a standard code module, and will process each row of data into the fields. You can place your cursor anywhere in the code module, and hit f5, and it will run.

I STRONG (but really STRONG) suggest you test his code on a copy of the database in case it messes your data up beyond repair.

```
Sub SpltNames()

  Dim rstData    As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strTable   As String

  Dim vBuf       As Variant        ' array to hold 3 parts
  Dim vBuf2      As Variant        ' for first and middle initials

  Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblCustomers")

  Do While rstData.EOF = False

     rstData.Edit

     ' split the 3 parts into the 3 fields.
     If InStr(rstData!FullName, ",") = 0 Then
        ' name has no , so assume just a last name
        rstData!Last_name = Trim(rstData!FullName)
     Else
        ' data has a , - split into parts
        vBuf = Split(rstData!FullName, ",")
        Select Case UBound(vBuf)
           Case 0
              ' no comma, assume just a last name
              rstData!Last_name = vBuf(0)
           Case 1
              ' 2 values, like Kallal, Albert, or Kallal, Albert D.
              rstData!Last_name = Trim(vBuf(0))

              ' take second part, and check for space for middle
              vBuf2 = Split(Trim(vBuf(1)), " ")

              Select Case UBound(vBuf2)
                 Case 0
                    ' no middle, just take first name
                    rstData!FirstName = Trim(vBuf2(0))
                 Case 1
                    ' a space between first and middle, save both
                    rstData!FirstName = Trim(vBuf2(0))
                    rstData!MName = Trim(vBuf2(1))
              End Select
        End Select
    End If
    rstData.Update    ' save data
    rstData.MoveNext  ' move on to next recod
 Loop

 rstData.Clone

 MsgBox "done processing"


End Sub
```